# Countdown Jquery

Tags: jquery, countdown

I have problem with jquery , I use the following code to get the dates in format json, this code works correctly.

In the console.log(tiempo) I can see this dates

```
2015/11/21 12:34:56
ex.html:15 2016/10/10 12:34:56
ex.html:15 2017/10/10 12:34:56
ex.html:15 2018/10/10 12:34:56
ex.html:15 2019/10/10 12:34:56
```

However in the HTML I only can see the first date I recieve from json.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function tiempo(tiempo){
        console.log(tiempo);
        $('.clock').countdown(tiempo, function(event) {
            $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
        });
    }    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = [
        {"transporte":"Servei de Rodalies Barcelona","now":"2015/11/21 12:34:56"},
        {"transporte":"Serveis Regionals","now":"2016/10/10 12:34:56"},
        {"transporte":"Ferrocarrils","now":"2017/10/10 12:34:56"},
        {"transporte":"Metro","now":"2018/10/10 12:34:56"},
        {"transporte":"Tram","now":"2019/10/10 12:34:56"}
    ];
    jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value) {
        $( ".prueba" ).append('<div class="clock"></div>');
        tiempo(value.now);
    });
</script>
```

An image is better to explain.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Wihich this code , I only show One date

```
<body>
    <div class="clock"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function tiempo(tiempo){
        $('.clock').countdown(tiempo, function(event) {
            $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
        });
    }    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = [
        {"transporte":"Servei de Rodalies Barcelona","now":"2015/11/21 12:34:56"},
        {"transporte":"Serveis Regionals","now":"2016/10/10 12:34:56"},
        {"transporte":"Ferrocarrils","now":"2017/10/10 12:34:56"},
        {"transporte":"Metro","now":"2018/10/10 12:34:56"},
        {"transporte":"Tram","now":"2019/10/10 12:34:56"}
    ];
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; ++i ) {
        tiempo(arr[i].now);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what does the _countdown_ function do? is it a `jquery` plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this piece of code (specifically the selector: `.clock`):

```
$('.clock').countdown(tiempo, function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
 });
```

What you are doing here is setting the value of all the `div` elements with the class `clock`, not just the last one you created.

There are a number of solutions to your problem, but the one that requires the minimum amount of change is to use the `jquery` function `last` like so (to pick the last element from the set):

```
$('.clock').last().countdown(tiempo, function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard `for` loop to iterate through objects:

```
var arr = [
    {"transporte":"Servei de Rodalies Barcelona","now":"2015/11/21 12:34:56"},
    {"transporte":"Serveis Regionals","now":"2016/10/10 12:34:56"},
    {"transporte":"Ferrocarrils","now":"2017/10/10 12:34:56"},
    {"transporte":"Metro","now":"2018/10/10 12:34:56"},
    {"transporte":"Tram","now":"2019/10/10 12:34:56"}
];
for ( var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; ++i ) {
    console.log(arr[i].now);
    $( ".prueba" ).append('<div class="clock"></div>');
    tiempo(value.now);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you throw the ````$( ".prueba" ).append('<div class="clock"></div>');```` in there like before, I was just trying to point you in the right direction by showing you how to iterate through an object

Answer (score 0):

Make this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    var element = $('<div class="clock"></div>').html(tiempo(value.now));
    $(".prueba").append(element);
}
```

And that's all